# NVIZ not working with QGIS 2.16 and GRASS 7 (mac)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d, nviz

I am trying to display 3d data in NVIZ (ideally i would like both raster and vector files in 3d) but when I run the NVIZ tool, nothing is returned. Im running QGIS 2.16.3 with the GRASS 7 plugin installed (GRASS mapset is activated).

I am using projected rasters stored in QGIS.

**I notice that when i put these rasters into a GRASS location they are not recognized by the NVIZ tool at all.

I have read that some people have had success installing a stand alone version of GRASS, but I would rather avoid this if possible.

Comment: After trying again i found this in the output log:    **/Users/myname/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh: line 5: nviz: command not found**    Where should the nviz command be stored?

Comment: Try 3D map generator (Adobe photoshop plugin)

Comment: The question is for an application inside QGIS... 3D map generator does it?